# Can we change class from uiview to uiscrollview in nib without changing constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nib, size-classes

Can we change class from uiview to uiscrollview in nib without changing constraints. I have view and i want to change to scroll view .

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to do a minor adjustment.

The problem that you will be facing is, that the `UIScrollView` has a `contentView` that contains your views.

You will have to set constraints for height and width of the `UIScrollView` in the storyboard, the rest will stay the same